# Как отсортировать список по значениям другого списка?

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Допустим дан список [4, 3, 7, 'dfg'] нужно отсортировать этот список в порядке другого списка [1, 2, 3, 4], а если значения не совпадают поместить их в конец. То есть должно получится [3, 4, 7, 'dfg']

Comment: Берём два цикла и прогоняем один в другом, используем внутри условие и новый список. Ну это так, вкратце

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идеи те же что и в [ответе CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1344324/416121). Промежуточный словарь обеспечивает производительность при длинных списках:

```
l1 = [4, 3, 7, 'dfg']
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# отображает значения на индексы
keys = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(l2)}

# индекс для значений вне списка
last_key = len(l2)

# сортирует по индексам, ненайденные значения скапливаются в конце
print(sorted(l1, key=lambda v: keys.get(v, last_key)))
```

> ```
> [3, 4, 7, 'dfg']
> ```

Comment: А, точно `len` нужен, с `max` я протупил, конечно )

Answer (score 2):

Вообще задачка прикольная, поэтому вот вам однострочник (не самый эффективный, но рабочий). Я просто задал ключ сортировки согласно описанию задачи:

```
l1 = [4, 3, 7, 'dfg']
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(sorted(l1, key=lambda x: l2.index(x) if x in l2 else len(l2)))
```

Вывод:

```
[3, 4, 7, 'dfg']
```

Хотя учебные задачи вам бы надо решать самому, чтобы чему-то научиться, они для этого и даются.